# Which one should be used in React, l10n or i18n?

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization, translate

I have a webpage in React and I wanted to use l10n (localization) but only find information about i18n (internationalization), so I don't know if l10n exists for React or if I'm forced to use i18n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l10n stands for localization and i18n stands for internationalization.

Localization is the process of guaranteeing your resources are focused on the requirements of one specific audience.
The use of it is about adapting your entire content so that it meets the norms and expectations of a specific location or market.

To know more about localization, have a look at [this blog post](https://locize.com/blog/localization/).

The internationalization process covers the design and development. So basically it is the task of instrumentalization (adaption) of your software code to be ready to be localized (not only translated) for other languages, regions and cultures. Think about ltr or rtl, currencies, date formats, etc...
Usually an i18n framework is used to help with this tasks.
Since you're talking about React.js, you may have a look at [this step by step guide for react-i18next](https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/).

To know more about internationalization, have a [look at this blog post](https://locize.com/blog/what-is-i18n/).

There is also globalization, for that have a look at [this](https://locize.com/blog/globalization-vs-localization/).

So tldr; There's a lot to think about when internationalizing a webpage.
More information can be found here:

- [What is Software Localization](https://locize.com/blog/what-is-software-localization/)
- [Is your software ready for localization?](https://locize.com/blog/is-your-software-ready-for-localization/)
- [How to localize your website](https://locize.com/blog/website-localization/)

Comment: Yes, i understand that, but my question is if i'ts possible to use l10n in react cause i don't find anything about l10n, only i18n. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by l10n?

Comment: Localization, sorry in mi enterprise they say l10n

Comment: before you start with localization for a webpage, you need to prepare your code and this is called internationalization (i18n)